# Error in getting topic title in D2L

Tags: desire2learn, valence

So I am trying to get the quiz names from course in D2L using this API `GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/content/topics/(topicId)` http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#get--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-content-topics-(topicId)

But I am response which has wrong topic 'Title' field.

```
GET /d2l/api/le/1.4/6671/content/topics/1134
```

`Response: 
{
    "DueDate": null,
    "TopicType": 3,
    "Url": "/d2l/common/dialogs/quickLink/quickLink.d2l?ou=66xx&type=quiz&rCode=1A4DE57C-F-3xx",
    "StartDate": null,
    "EndDate": null,
    "IsHidden": false,
    "IsLocked": false,
    "Id": 1134,
    "Title": "/d2l/common/dialogs/quickLink/quickLink.d2l?ou={orgUnitId}&type=quiz&rCode=1A4DE57C-F-3xx",
    "ShortTitle": "",
    "Type": 1
}`

I created this quiz directly from course module --> new --> new quiz. But If I create quiz from Quizzes (Top menu) --> Manage Quiz --> New quiz. Then I get correct Title. Do I need to add some settings in quiz to get correct Title?  Is there better way to get names?
We are running v10.3 of LMS

Comment: Second opption is Quizzes (Top menu) --> Manage Quiz --> New quiz --> go to any module --> add existing activities --> select quiz you just created.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue, and will be addressed with due priority but D2L currently does not have an expected timeline for fixing it. If you'd like to track the status of this issue, or lobby for an increased priority on this issue, D2L encourages you to do so via your account or partner manager, or approved support contact.